# Consolidate Duplicate Rows (Records) Based on Name in Microsoft Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like to consolidate Rows 1 to 10 based on "Name" so that the values in the "Group" columns are in 1 row. The anticipated result: Only 1 record would remain and show that the user (Zen Lookout) is in Groups 1 to 10 (indicated by the value "X"). I am cleaning up a database with duplicate "Name" values.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

#### Formula in `B27`

Copy an paste down `B28`, `B29`, etc as needed.

```
=BYCOL($C$26#, LAMBDA(y,
  LET(array,FILTER($B$1:$L$21,$B$1:$B$21=B27),
          _col, INDEX(array, ,MATCH(y,$B$1:$L$1,0)),
           IFERROR(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,FILTER(_col,_col="x")),""))))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I reproduced what you have suggested, and only the UNIQUE formula worked. The other returned a #REF!. Is there a way to share my file?

Comment: If you look at the content of the `#REF!` error it is likely that there is data in cells that would be overwritten by the results of the formula.  The `#REF!` will list the first cell that is in its way.

Comment: I added...
=UNIQUE(B2:B21) 
...to B27
...and...
=BYCOL($C$26#, LAMBDA(y,LET(array,FILTER($B$1:$L$21,$B$1:$B$21=B27),_col, INDEX(array,MATCH(y,$B$1:$L$1,0)),IFERROR(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,FILTER(_col,_col="x")),""))))
...to C27
...but I still get #REF!. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Hover over the error and see what the actual text of it is

Comment: Also a screenshot [like this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tBBy.png) would be helpful